# On branch main Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'. not letting me commit with github desktop, but lets me commit with the terminal

Tags: git, macos, github

When i am trying to commit changes to main on github desktop it says this: [image: error]

and it doesnt let me commit on the app.
but when i go to the terminal
this is my git status:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   mc/__pycache__/settings.cpython-311.pyc
    modified:   mc/__pycache__/urls.cpython-311.pyc
    modified:   mc/urls.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(base) coding-workspace@Ashs-Mac-Studio mc %
```

after i do

```
(base) coding-workspace@Ashs-Mac-Studio mc % git add .
(base) coding-workspace@Ashs-Mac-Studio mc % git commit -m "all"
[main da979312] all
 3 files changed, 1 insertion(+)
(base) coding-workspace@Ashs-Mac-Studio mc % git push
Enumerating objects: 12, done.
Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.18 KiB | 1.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 5 local objects.
To https://github.com/ashgharibyan/mc.git
   4cde31d3..da979312  main -> main
(base) coding-workspace@Ashs-Mac-Studio mc %
```

I dont understand why commit and pushing works on the terminal but not in the app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both GitHub Desktop and Git in the Terminal were the same Git and were following exactly the same rules. Git has an *index* that is where you construct a commit. If you don't put any modified files into the index, there is nothing to commit.

> after i do
>
> ```
> (base) coding-workspace@Ashs-Mac-Studio mc % git add .
> ```

Yup, and that's the whole point right there. When you got to the Terminal, you said `git add .` which adds the modified files to the index, and so you now *did* have something to commit.

And it's the same in GitHub Desktop. You had nothing modified in the index so there  was nothing to commit; and, *as the error message says clearly* in your screenshot, you needed to say `git add` first in order to commit.

But you didn't. Instead, you walked away from GitHub Desktop and did the `git add` in the Terminal — which is fine too. But you *could* have done it in GitHub Desktop. You just chose not to.

> but when i go to the terminal this is my git status

I don't understand your use of the word "but". Your git status in the Terminal, which you have quoted for us, is *exactly 100% identical* to what the message in GitHub Desktop said, which you have shown in a screenshot. They are *exactly the same!*

It seems to me that the problem is merely that you don't understand how to interact with GitHub Desktop. And that's fine; it isn't really doing anything useful for you. Personally I like the Terminal best. I suggest sticking with that.

Comment: yes I undestand that, but as you can see in the github desktop i have selected the modified files(which is basically git add in the desktop app) and wrote a commit message, and it still gave me that error. Ive done this to my other projects, by just selecting and commiting, but idk why this time it doesnt work